# PuppeteerSharp : PDF generation of page with scroll

Tags: puppeteer, html-to-pdf, puppeteer-sharp

We have a very long report in angular HTML, which is visible full on scroll only.
Whenever we are taking PDF for that report its not exporting the whole page (or multiple pages)
The content which is visible after scroll is not exported in to PDF.

can anyone help me over here how to do manage this is puppeteerSharp.

Comment: How does it look when you do a print to PDF in chrome?

Comment: Its also creating just one page, content after scroll is not there.